# Azure release pipeline, passing variable to power-shell script is not giving desired output

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, powershell-2.0, azure-powershell

In Azure release pipeline (using GUI) I am using an inline PS script task which checks for Folder names and File extensions. The script works if I provide the folders and extensions values directly into **Where-Object** cmdlet, e.g.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path | `
      Where-Object { ($_.Name -in "ConsoleApps","WebDeployParameters") -or ($_.Extension -in ".xml",".config",".asax")}
```

But it does not work if I create and pass the Variables:
[image]

into **where-object** cmdlet:

```
$path = "$($env:DropLocation)\$($env:CurrentRelease)\"

$Names = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | `
      Where-Object { ($_.Name -in $env:FoldersName) -or ($_.Extension -in $env:FileExtensions)} 
#| Remove-Item -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

write-host $Names
```

Could someone point out, what might be going wrong here? Because the same code works if I run it on my local machine:

```
$FileExtensions = ".xml",".config",".asax"
$FoldersName = "ConsoleApps","WebDeployParameters"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path | `
      Where-Object { ($_.Name -in $FoldersName) -or ($_.Extension -in $FileExtensions)}
```

**Attached is an image of the pipeline:**
[image]

Comment: Have you done any preliminary debugging by checking to see if the environment variables you think should exist actually do exist?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply. Yes, I did the debugging and can see the variables value in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a pipeline variable into the script the syntax is $(variable_name).

Instead of $env:variable_name

Here is an example I use to pass pipeline variables into my scripts:
[image]

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash) is the Microsoft documentation on setting variables in scripts.

Comment: Hi @SenseiMcKellar, Thanks for your answer. I am going to accept it because it fixed my problem but on the other hand the syntax $env:variable_name still seems valid because i have used it in other pipelines and tasks of the same pipeline and that syntax gives the desired output. Not sure though, why it was not working in this particular situation.

Comment: *When you pass a pipeline variable into the script the syntax is $(variable_name).*. This is a vast oversimplification, which will lead others to confusion. `$env:X` is **PowerShell** syntax for accessing an environment variable. `$(X)` is **Azure Pipelines** macro syntax for accessing an **Azure Pipelines** variable. When you use `$(X)`, it's actually doing a string replacement on your in-line script while compiling the template. The value, from PowerShell's perspective, is hard-coded.

Comment: In general, Azure Pipelines variables are accessible as environment variables within PowerShell, Bash, and CLI scripts. *Secret* variables, however, are **not**. Those have to be explicitly mapped as environment variables in an `env:` block within a YAML pipeline, or by mapping them in the `Environment` section of the step in the GUI editor of a classic pipeline.

Comment: @DanielMann Thanks for providing the more clear explanation of difference between Azure vs Powershell variables in current context.